# MariaDB Refusing LOCALHOST connections

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lua

I'm wondering how I can troubleshoot what's happening, there is not enough details to reproduce the problem and find a fix, here it is what I found:

1)The script does many queries every couple of minutes to the localhost MariaDB server
2)The queries are Async, so multiple queries start failing at some point, once these queries fail, I'm unable to access MariaDB command line, with error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

In some rare cases I'm able to access it(the commandline admin "mariadb"), any query would fail with the same error.

3. In the mysql logs file I can see the error:

> [Warning] Aborted connection x to db:  'Dbname' user: 'useraccessingdb' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Following that line there are many more, at the same time, usually having a connection number from 9 to 19 (aborted connection x=9/19).

How can I debug the issue?
What could be the issue?
Thanks for Your time.
The OS is Ubuntu 19
MariaDB is version 10.3.22

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a firewall error.

Try launching `gufw` and see what rules you have enabled.
Possibly just the default `allow outgoing, reject incoming`

Even though localhost is the same machine, it sees *any traffic trying to access a port as incoming*, so you need to specifically allow it for your database port.

You'll have to check the documentation to find out what port that is.  I've played around with those before, but I don't remember which the default is, though it may be specific to your purposes.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/what-ufw-rule-will-allow-port-80-to-localhost-but-only-from-localhost-4175595450

---

Alternatively, you can just use a blanket `allow all local traffic` which should be fine for what you're doing.

[image: 127.0.0.1]

Also, doublecheck that your `hosts` file has localhost defined
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

I've run into a case where it wasn't.